# CGRectMake( ) - y reference looks totally wrong

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am facing a really strange issue:

I am instantiating multiple `UIImageView` inside a `for loop` with the method `CGRectMake`, the y origin I am giving seems to be totally wrong on the screen:

Here is my code:

```
- (void)makeTheView
{
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    UIScrollView *header = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 64, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];
    header.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:254/255.0f green:255/255.0f blue:213/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

    [self.view addSubview:header];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        UIImageView *avatar = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5 + i * 75, 5, 70, 70)];
        avatar.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bo_pic_baby5.jpg"];
        [avatar.layer setCornerRadius:8.0];
        avatar.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

        NSLog(@"%f", avatar.frame.origin.y);

        UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, avatar.frame.size.width, 20)];
        title.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:148/255.0f green:148/255.0f blue:148/255.0f alpha:0.5f];
        title.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
        title.text = @"崔健";
        title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        [avatar addSubview:title];

        [header addSubview:avatar];
    }
}
```

According to this code `avatar` is within `header` at 5px from the top of `header`.

But the following is what I obtain visually:

[image]

**note: when the white area begin, the `header` view stopped**

This is not a real issue since I can reevaluate my frames like this :

```
CGRectMake(5 + i * 75, - 20, 70, 70)
```

but it looks really weird, and I am quite sure I am missing something totally trivial here...

Comment: Your scroll view is 64 from the view and header is 5 from the scroll view. So the y is totally 69 from actual view.

Comment: @MidhunMP But I am adding my multiple `UIImageView` within the `header` at 5px from the top of it (according to the code), actually the space between the top of the `header` and the top of my `avatar` are more than 5px... (PS: self.view.backgroundColor is set to whiteColor)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will be fixed by:

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Since iOS 7, view controllers automatically adjust scroll view insets so that the scroll view content is not hidden behind the navigation bar because it expects scroll views to start at the top of the screen.

However, the usual solution is to just set the scrollview `frame.origin.y` to `0`.

Comment: This fixed the issue, thank you. I think your explanation are pretty clear but I do not understand why it is acting like this since my `parent view` (the header) is positioned under the `UINavigationBar`?
By the way, this was the answer to my question, thank you again

Comment: @sebastienFCT With a translucent navigation bar, the controller just expects the scroll view to start at the top because otherwise there is no reason to actually have a translucent navigation bar (when you scroll up, the content won't be visible behind the bar). That's what most people want to do. Your case is a bit special, that's why you have to modify the default settings. This magic caused a lot of questions here on SO when iOS 7 was new.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is really clear now. And sorry if I wasn't able to find these source in SO before posting

Answer (score 0):

Your Code is Absolutely Correct , As you are Adding the scrollview on (0,64) Position , So 64 will be count from Bottom of the Navigation Bar, If you want it on top (Just Below the Navigation bar), Change this declaration to as below :

```
UIScrollView *header = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100)];
```

Comment: My `header` is located exactly where I wanted it to be, apparently this `scrollView` is generated many confusion, but my issue is really the position of the `UIImageView` within this header which are not at 5px from the top of their parent (the `header`)